# Node export object with data from file

Tags: javascript, node.js, filereader

I am exporting the following object which initializes its data from a file

```
function wordsBox(){
    this.words= {};
}

var w = new wordsBox();

fs.readFile('words.txt', function (err, data) {
    w.words = JSON.parse(data.toString());
});

module.exports = w;
```

However, when I try to access the data from another file, its not reading.

```
var wordsBox = require('../db/word.reader');
console.log(wordsBox.words);
```

The following comes out an empty object.  Therefore, is there anyway to export the object after the fs has finished reading the data.

Comment: in the "other" file, you didn't wait long enough for the readFile in the module to complete. Since you didn't give yourself a promise or a callback to work with, you'll have to guestimate with setTimeout (or modify the module to have a callback)

Comment: is the best way to have a callback called when the readFile is complete?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's the "best" way, but it's one of two ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the sync version of fs.readFile:

```
... 
var data = fs.readFileSync('words.txt')
w.words = JSON.parse(data.toString())
```

Requiring ("loading") other modules is a synchronous operation. If you want to populate your data from external resources, you have to do it synchronously too. However, I recommend to employ explicit (and optionally async) initialization of modules to leverage testing and avoid unexpected side effects.